# Can we change stripes keys in cashier dynamically in laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-8, laravel-cashier

I am using stripe with Laravel cashier. I want to make stripe keys dynamic instead of saving keys in .env file. I saved keys in database and now want to use these keys in cashier. Cashier get these keys from .env but i want to get these from database.

[image]

this is laravel/cashier/config/casher.php file where it access keys and i want to set my values there. I can't use eloquent in this file.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I updated the stripe keys in the env file with the a function in controller.

```
protected function updateDotEnv($key, $newValue, $delim='')
{

    $path = base_path('.env');
    // get old value from current env
    $oldValue = env($key);

    // was there any change?
    if ($oldValue === $newValue) {
        return;
    }

    // rewrite file content with changed data
    if (file_exists($path)) {
        // replace current value with new value 
        file_put_contents(
            $path, str_replace(
                $key.'='.$delim.$oldValue.$delim, 
                $key.'='.$delim.$newValue.$delim, 
                file_get_contents($path)
            )
        );
    }
}
```

$key is new name of variable in env and $newValue is the updated key.

Comment: According to my opinion the env variables shouldn't be modified as env variables are not made for modifications, instead they should guide the app wih robust values. You should try another trick/hack to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the config before using anything related to stripe or on your model you can create a static function to override the defaults but this way you will need to use stripe through the model

```php
    public static function stripe(array $options = [])
    {
        return Cashier::stripe(array_merge([
            'api_key' => $this->getStripeKey(),
        ], $options));
    }
```

or update the config

```php
config(['cashier.secret' => $key])
```

Comment: Thank you! It looks right. But I solved this problem. I updated the keys direct in env file with a function in controller when ever i need to update.